Docker buildx with GitHub Actions
I have a monorepo that has 3 apps. I want to use GitHub actions to run some tests. The setup works fine if I use docker build instead of docker buildx. However this has some issues with buildx.
What I am trying to achieve with buildx is to cache these Docker images. I have this in my package.json which uses Dockerfile.base to build a Docker image base:latest:
"build:docker.base": "docker buildx build . -f ./Dockerfile.base -t 'base:latest' --cache-from=type=gha --cache-to=type=gha,mode=max",
"prebuild:docker": "npm run build:docker.base",
"build:docker": "docker images && npx lerna run build:docker",

Inside the apps, I have this command in package.json:
"build:docker": "APP_NAME=timer && docker buildx build . --build-arg APP=\"$APP\" -t \"superior/$APP:latest\" -f ../Dockerfile.app --cache-from=type=gha --cache-to=type=gha,mode=max",

This uses Dockerfile.app and accepts argument APP so that I can re-use this same file for all apps.
Workflow code is as follows:
- uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

- name: Build docker images
    run: npm run build:docker

I tried using the docker/build-push-action@v5 but as far as I know, this can accept only one Dockerfile and is not apt for this case.
Here are the logs:
> superior/timer:"build:docker"


> superior/timer@0.7.9 build:docker
> APP_NAME=timer && docker buildx build . --build-arg APP_NAME="$APP_NAME" -t "superior/$APP_NAME:latest" -f .././docker/Dockerfile.app --cache-from=type=gha --cache-to=type=gha,mode=max

#0 building with "builder-d54732d8-cdc2-43ef-ac94-230f778ffefa" instance using docker-container driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.app
#1 transferring dockerfile: 1.26kB done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:21.7.2
#2 DONE 0.1s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/superior/base:latest
#3 ERROR: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/superior/base:latest:
------
WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
Dockerfile.app:21
--------------------
  19 |     COPY --from=superior/base:latest /app/apps/${APP_NAME}/src/schem[a] src/schema
  20 | >>> COPY --from=superior/base:latest /app/node_modules/swagger-ui-dist node_modules/swagger-ui-dist
  21 |     
  22 |     COPY --from=superior/base:latest app/esbuild-dist/${APP_NAME} ${APP_NAME}
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: superior/base:latest: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/superior/base:latest: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
npm ERR! Lifecycle script `build:docker` failed with error: 
npm ERR! Error: command failed 
npm ERR!   in workspace: superior/timer@0.7.9 
npm ERR!   at location: /home/runner/work/superior/superior/apps/timer 


"this has some issues" - what issues?

Updated with logs.
